# AngularJS - Run mandrill service

Tags: angularjs, firebase, mandrill

I'm building a small app that needs to send mail through mandrill every hour or so.  I want to bind the function that does this to the right location in the app.

Basically, I have a Firebase reference with dates/times, and every hour, I need Mandrill to run through that Firebase array and send emails accordingly.  I have a simple Mandrill service I can use, just need to know where the best place to put the actual sending logic is.

Basic Mandrill service:

```
.factory('mandrill', function() {
       return {
         initMandrill: function() {
           return new mandrill.Mandrill('XXX', true);
         }
       };
     });
```

Comment: this seems like a good place to add another function that can be invoked for send(). I would suggest that instead of returning a new mandrill, you can use the init fucntion to setup a variable in the factory itself. The outside client doesn't need to have a reference to the Mandrill object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like the below using the Mandrill JSON API. You could call it from the factory working against your Firebase, passing in the object data you want to distribute.

```
.factory('Mandrill', ['$http',
    function($http) {

      /*=======================*/
      /*  Insert Emails Here
      /*=======================*/

      var fromEmail = 'email';
      var fromName = 'email_name';
      var replyTo = 'email';

      return {
        messageWork: function(resp) {
          return $http.post('https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0//messages/send.json', {
            'key': mandrillkey,
            'message': {
              'html': '<p>Unknown Message</p><p>' + resp + '</p><p>Code:' + resp.messagetext + '</p>',
              'text': resp,
              'subject': 'Unknown Message',
              'from_email': fromEmail,
              'from_name': fromName,
              'to': [
              {
                'email': resp.toEmail,
                'name': resp.toName,
                'type': 'to'
              }
              ],
              'headers': {
                'Reply-To': replyTo
              }
            }
          })
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            // log success
          });
        }
      };
  }]);
```

I would wonder though if Angular is the best use case for this type of work due to a) your stated time constraint (hourly) and b) the exposure of your Mandrill keys in the client code. [If you look at the integration options](https://mandrillapp.com/docs/integrations.html), they offer a few backend solutions.

I would suggest you maybe look at using Node for this type of work, [node-schedule](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule) or [later](https://github.com/bunkat/later) would handle your timing patterns, and Mandrill has a [node API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.nodejs.html) as [does Firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase). Just a thought.

Comment: Has anyone ever told you that you are a champ?  Regardless, node-schedule looks very very useful... thanks a ton.

Comment: Glad it was helpful - this is a write up I did a little bit ago on using node API w/ Angular client in case you're interested. http://matthewgladney.com/blog/angular/using-mandrill-with-the-node-api-and-an-angular-client/